# gradleでipaファイルを作成したい

Tags: ios, xcode, gradle, build

お世話になります

gradleでadhocビルドを通して、ipaファイルを作成したいと考えております
以下のページを参考にトライしてます。
http://qiita.com/bilyakudan/items/b53350a6702f14128ebb

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
        maven {
          url('http://openbakery.org/repository/')
        }
        mavenCentral()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.openbakery', name: 'xcodePlugin', version: '0.10.+'
      }
    }

    apply plugin: 'xcode'

    xcodebuild {
      scheme = 'NeoCafesagashi'
      target = 'NeoCafesagashi'
      workspace = 'NeoCafesagashi.xcworkspace'
      configuration = 'adhoc'
      sdk = 'iphoneos'
      signing{
        identity = 'iPhone Distribution: xxxxxx xxxxx (xxxxx)' 
        mobileProvisionURI = 'file://localhost/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.mobileprovision'
      }

    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '1.10'
    }
```

gradleでビルド自動化も古いのかもしれませんが、せっかくgradleやり始めたのでトライしたいなと。。。

以下のエラーで詰まってしまい、先に進めず。。。

```
            gradle package --stacktrace
:cocoapods
Skipping installing pods, because the Pods directory already exists
:xcodebuildConfig
:infoplistModify
Updating /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/NeoCafesagashi/NeoCafesagashi-Info.plist
:keychainClean
:keychainCreate
:provisioningClean
:provisioningInstall
:xcodebuild
Done
:archive
convert plist to binary /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/archive/NeoCafesagashi.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NeoCafesagashi.app/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboardc/Info.plist
convert plist to binary /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/archive/NeoCafesagashi.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NeoCafesagashi.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/VersionInfo.plist
convert plist to binary /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/archive/NeoCafesagashi.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NeoCafesagashi.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/Info.plist
convert plist to binary /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/archive/NeoCafesagashi.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NeoCafesagashi.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/Info.plist
convert plist to binary /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/archive/NeoCafesagashi.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NeoCafesagashi.app/Info.plist
convert plist to binary /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/archive/NeoCafesagashi.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NeoCafesagashi.app/Main_iPad.storyboardc/Info.plist
convert plist to binary /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/archive/NeoCafesagashi.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NeoCafesagashi.app/ResourceRules.plist
:package
Set Info Plist Value: Delete CFBundleResourceSpecification
Codesign with Identity: iPhone Distribution: SHUNSUKE HIRATSUKA (GSX2TRMV6J)
Codesign /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/codesign/Payload/NeoCafesagashi.app
:package FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':package'.
> Command failed to run (exit code 1): '/usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --sign iPhone Distribution: SHUNSUKE HIRATSUKA (GSX2TRMV6J) --verbose /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/codesign/Payload/NeoCafesagashi.app --keychain /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/codesign/gradle-1425976325486.keychain'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        * Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':package'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.openbakery.CommandRunnerException: Command failed to run (exit code 1): '/usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --sign iPhone Distribution: SHUNSUKE HIRATSUKA (GSX2TRMV6J) --verbose /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/codesign/Payload/NeoCafesagashi.app --keychain /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/codesign/gradle-1425976325486.keychain'
    at org.openbakery.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.groovy:88)
    at org.openbakery.CommandRunner$run$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.openbakery.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.groovy:154)
    at org.openbakery.CommandRunner$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.openbakery.signing.PackageTask.codesign(PackageTask.groovy:161)
    at org.openbakery.signing.PackageTask.this$6$codesign(PackageTask.groovy)
    at org.openbakery.signing.PackageTask$this$6$codesign$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.openbakery.signing.PackageTask.packageApplication(PackageTask.groovy:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 44 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 34.185 secs
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プラグイン作った人に直接質問して解決しました

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url('http://openbakery.org/repository/')
    }
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath group: 'org.openbakery', name: 'xcodePlugin', version: '0.10.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'xcode'

xcodebuild {
  scheme = 'NeoCafesagashi'
  target = 'NeoCafesagashi'
  workspace = 'NeoCafesagashi.xcworkspace'
  configuration = 'adhoc'
  sdk = 'iphoneos'
  signing{
    identity = 'iPhone Distribution: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX)' 
    mobileProvisionURI = 'file://localhost/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/cafesagashi_adhoc201503.mobileprovision'
    certificateURI = 'file://localhost/Users/shiratsu/push_notification_info/shiratsu_distribution2.p12'
    certificatePassword = 'XXXXXXX'
  }

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

お騒がせしました